# For a combinatorial proof of a symmetric identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-identities, bijective-combinatorics

In my paper [Supercongruences involving dual sequences [Finite Fields Appl. 46(2017), 179-216]](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ffa.2017.03.007), I gave a new symmetric identity which states that if $x+y=-1$ then 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom xk^2\binom{y+z}{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom yk^2\binom{x+z}{n-k}.$$
(See (1.17) of the paper.)

QUESTION: Is there a combinatorial proof of the above symmetric identity?